# Swing Accessing Another Window Fault

Tags: java, swing, passwords, verification

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

/* PasswordDemo.java requires no other files. */

public class PasswordDemo extends JPanel
                          implements ActionListener {
    private static String OK = "ok";
    private static String HELP = "help";

    private JFrame controllingFrame; //needed for dialogs
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public PasswordDemo(JFrame f) {
        //Use the default FlowLayout.
        controllingFrame = f;

        //Create everything.
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        passwordField.setActionCommand(OK);
        passwordField.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the password: ");
        label.setLabelFor(passwordField);

        JComponent buttonPane = createButtonPanel();

        //Lay out everything.
        JPanel textPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        textPane.add(label);
        textPane.add(passwordField);

        add(textPane);
        add(buttonPane);
    }

    protected JComponent createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        JButton helpButton = new JButton("Help");

        okButton.setActionCommand(OK);
        helpButton.setActionCommand(HELP);
        okButton.addActionListener(this);
        helpButton.addActionListener(this);

        p.add(okButton);
        p.add(helpButton);

        return p;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        if (OK.equals(cmd)) { //Process the password.
            char[] input = passwordField.getPassword();
            if (isPasswordCorrect(input)) {
             //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
             //       "Success! You typed the right password.");

                class BasicPanel extends JPanel {
                    public BasicPanel() {
                        JButton button = new JButton("New...");
                        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                test2 inputForm = new test2();
                                inputForm.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        });
                        add(button);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
                    "Invalid password. Try again.",
                    "Error Message",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            //Zero out the possible password, for security.
            Arrays.fill(input, '0');

            passwordField.selectAll();
            resetFocus();
        } else { //The user has asked for help.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
                "You can get the password by searching this example's\n"
              + "source code for the string \"correctPassword\".\n"
              + "Or look at the section How to Use Password Fields in\n"
              + "the components section of The Java Tutorial.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the passed-in array against the correct password.
     * After this method returns, you should invoke eraseArray
     * on the passed-in array.
     */
    private static boolean isPasswordCorrect(char[] input) {
        boolean isCorrect = true;
        char[] correctPassword = { 'b', 'u'};

        if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
            isCorrect = false;
        } else {
            isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
        }

        //Zero out the password.
        Arrays.fill(correctPassword,'0');

        return isCorrect;
    }

    //Must be called from the event dispatch thread.
    protected void resetFocus() {
        passwordField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    class test2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public test2() {
            initComponents();
        }
        private void initComponents() {

            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jButton1.setText("jButton1");

            jButton2.setText("jButton2");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
            jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
            jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addContainerGap(196, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addContainerGap(174, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(92, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        // Variables declaration - do not modify
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        // End of variables declaration
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PasswordDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        final PasswordDemo newContentPane = new PasswordDemo(frame);
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Make sure the focus goes to the right component
        //whenever the frame is initially given the focus.
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                newContentPane.resetFocus();
            }
        });

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hey there everyone, i am trying to access another window using swing. I am trying to do so via password verification, when the use inputs the right password it should grant them access to the form fillout page which i am building. Problem is that there is something wrong when i input the right password and click "OK". Its not going through and giving me access to the next page. I just need pointers as to what i should fix.
The method that should be granting access to the other window
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
Thank you very much.

Comment: @ Frisbetarian I have same answer as on OTN, please edit your post and add notice about crossposting with link to OTN

Comment: @mKorbel: what forum is "OTN"?

Comment: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=950&start=0

Answer (score 0):

You never make a new `BasicPanel`. You can do this instead.

```
if (isPasswordCorrect(input)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
        "Success! Click OK for the next screen.");
    test2 inputForm = new test2();
    inputForm.setVisible(true);
} ...
```